# Modules and interfaces can have the same name?

Tags: typescript

The following seems to be legal typescript:

```
interface Vec2 {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}

module Vec2 {
    export function create(x?: number, y?: number) : Vec2 {
        return {x: x||0, y: y||0};
    }
    export function length(v: Vec2) : number {
        return Math.sqrt(v.x * v.x + v.y * v.y);
    }
}

const v:Vec2 = Vec2.create(1, 2);
const len = Vec2.length(v);
```

Which is kinda neat because you have a struct-type Vec2 and a module of functions that operate on Vec2 structs.
I'm wondering if this is a bad idea or not. Initially I thought I should get a compiler error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* do this with an interface and...

- A module / namespace
- A variable
- An ambient class

The compiler will actually warn you if you try to do this in a way that would cause compiler-danger - such as with an interface and a class (i.e. it wouldn't be able to infer which one you meant).

In some contexts it can make a lot of sense to use this trick, it is commonly employed in definition files, with an interface paired with a variable of the same name.

The acid test is: when you use this feature, does it cause you to have to think about what you mean when you see `Vec2` in your code? If it does, you should avoid it as it increases complexity unnecessarily. It it is obvious or irrelevant (as it is in definition files) - then go ahead and use it.

Comment: Thanks. I will try experimenting and see if I manage to confuse myself with it somehow. I'm finding functions operating on structs (interfaces) useful because it allows me to work with three.js vectors and cannon.js vectors in the same app more easily. But I'm never sure how to *name* things when the functions and data aren't part of the same class.